# How to draw an upsidedown square by dragging mouse?

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

How can I draw an inverted rectangle in Java using swing?

Using the 'g.drawRect(x,y,width,height)' method, 
Creating a rectangle through mouse drag was successful, but there was a slight error.

If you drag to a point (x2,y2| x2>x1 && y2>y1) larger than the first point(x,y), It will operate normally.

However, in the opposite case, if the coordinates of the drag point are smaller than the coordinates of the first click point, it is drawn in the opposite direction, not to the drag point direction.

Even if I tried to draw reverse it through if(), I couldn't figure out what to do.

The direction I want is like a dragging box in Window, but It's a little hard to me.
Please give me some hint to overcome this hard trip.

↓Here is my code

```
   class Rect {
            int x, y, w, h;
   }

   public class Rectangle extends JPanel{
            int i = 0;
       int x, y = 0;
       Rect [] ary = new Rect[100];
       public Rectangle() {
           addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
               public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
               public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
               public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
               public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                   if(i>100) return;
                   ary[i] = new Rect();
                   ary[i].x = e.getX(); ary[i].y = e.getY();
                   x= ary[i].x; y = ary[i].y;
               }

               @Override
               public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                   ary[i].w = Math.abs(ary[i].x-e.getX()); 
                        ary[i].h = Math.abs(ary[i].y- e.getY());
                   i++;
                   repaint();
               }
           });

           addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
               @Override
               public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                   ary[i].w = Math.abs(ary[i].x-e.getX()); 
                   ary[i].h = Math.abs(ary[i].y- e.getY());
                   repaint();
               }
               public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
               }
           });
       }

       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
           for(Rect r:ary){
               if(r !=null) {
                   g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                   g.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

please help me

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKLcB.png)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Ah..! I'll fix it thanks XD

Comment: Use the [edit] button below the post to make changes to it. This avoids overwriting the improvements made by other people!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
Thanks to your opinion, I could attach the image of the problem and simplify the code with the problem.

Comment: *"I could .. simplify the code"* No, you misunderstand what an MCVE / SSCCE is. There needed to be code **added** to what was there, to make it an MCVE / SSCCE. E.G. imports and a main method..

Comment: Ah.. I am not good at English yet, so I have not fully understood the concepts of MCVE and SSCE. I will read it again later and understand it. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't use an Array to store the Rectangle objects you want to paint. Use an ArrayList it will grow dynamically as you want to paint more rectangles.

The problem with your current code is that you are attempting to update the x/y/width/height values in 3 separate methods. This should only be done in the `mouseDragged` method.

The basic steps are:

1. in `mousePressed` you save the initial mouse point. Create an empty Rectangle object to used to draw the rectangle
2. in `mouseDragged` you compare the initial mouse point with the current mouse point and determine the minimum x/y values. You then get the absolute value for the x and y values separately so you know the width/height of the rectangle. Update the x/y/width/height values of your Rectangle object and repaint the Rectangle
3. in `mouseReleased` you add the Rectangle object to your ArrayList

See the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example that implements the above suggestion.

The MouseInputAdapter implementation from the above example is as follows. It shows how most of the logic is in the mouseDragged method:

```
class MyMouseListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    private Point startPoint;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        startPoint = e.getPoint();
        shape = new Rectangle();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int x = Math.min(startPoint.x, e.getX());
        int y = Math.min(startPoint.y, e.getY());
        int width = Math.abs(startPoint.x - e.getX());
        int height = Math.abs(startPoint.y - e.getY());

        shape.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (shape.width != 0 || shape.height != 0)
        {
            addRectangle(shape, e.getComponent().getForeground());
        }

        shape = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... 
There's another method to get the shape of a rectangle called setBounds().

I was easy to understand thanks to your kind and easy explanation. 
Thank you very very much, and have a nice day.

Comment: Wow, before calling the Rectangular() class and using the setBounds() method,

I could already draw a rectangle that I wanted, just  with a small value of x, y in the coordinates comparison between the click point and the current dragging mouse.

I would really appreciate hint that you gave me, so I couldreach the answer that I really really wanted. 

Thank you very much ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0):

because `ary[i].x` and `ary[i].y` must be the minimum among the press and release coordinates:

```
           @Override
           public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
               ary[i].w = Math.abs(ary[i].x-e.getX()); 
               ary[i].h = Math.abs(ary[i].y- e.getY());
               // upper left point
               ary[i].x = Math.min(ary[i].x,e.getX()); 
               ary[i].y = Math.min(ary[i].y,e.getY()); 
               i++;
               repaint();
           }
```

Comment: Then.. how do you make a rectangle with a starting point less than the coordinates of the end point by using g.drawRect() or other method like Polygon?

Comment: By definition of drawRect, x,y must be the left-upper point of the rectangle. Did you tried what I suggested? Isn't it what you need? If not explain.

Comment: Well, if it's bigger than the point where the x-coordinates are taken, I tried to reverse the value of x and width, but there's no fixed point.

Comment: I am sorry for the explanation so frustrating.